# How to divide screen into a grid using 2d arrays in swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Below is my code so far using for loops, and this is what it looks like right now. As you can see it is very condensed[image: this]

```
         for i in 0...12{
            for j in 0...16{
                
            let block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockImage, size: blockSize)
                block.position.x = block.frame.width/2 * CGFloat(j)+1
                block.position.y = frame.height - block.frame.height/2 * CGFloat(i)+1
                block.zPosition = 1
                
                
                addChild(block)
        }
        }
```

However, I am only trying to have **2 rows of blocks on the top** and **1 row of blocks on the bottom**. The screen should have a height 12 blocks and a width of 15 blocks.

Is there a way I can create a grid that is 15x12 with a cell size of 64x64 using 2d arrays? Because eventually, I want to add blocks to random cell locations in the grid(besides the fixed top and bottom rows)

I am looking for tutorials on how to do this, but I am finding people that use other open source options that are not included in swift. Please drop any tips or advice you have for me to tackle this I am very new to SpriteKit and Swift, thank you! (lmk if you need more clarification as well)

update:
I got it to look like this now, but I don't know how to remove the rest of the blocks that arent in the top and bottom rows. How would i get the location of each block?
[image]

```
  for i in 0...12{
            for j in 0...16{

            let block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockImage, size: blockSize)
                block.position.x = block.frame.width/2 + CGFloat((64*j))
                block.position.y = frame.height - block.frame.height/2 - CGFloat((64*i))
                block.zPosition = 1
                addChild(block)
        }
        }
```

Comment: Pay attention that 0…12 will produce 13 rows and 0…16 will produce 17 columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't really code for SpriteKit but maybe can offer some tips based on the logic I see.

One way could be to add some logic in the for loop to check if you are currently iterating the first 2 rows or the last row and only in these cases, add the row of blocks.

```
let rows = 12
let columns = 16

let topBoundary = 1

for i in 0...rows {
    for j in 0...columns {
        
        if i <= topBoundary || i == rows {
            let block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockImage, size: blockSize)
            block.position.x = block.frame.width/2 + CGFloat((64*j))
            block.position.y = frame.height - block.frame.height/2 - CGFloat((64*i))
            block.zPosition = 1
            addChild(block)
        }
    }
}
```